# Store Keystrokes in X++

Tags: axapta, x++

Does anybody knows how to store keystroke as a string in X++?

And also if I want to covert them to ASCII and vise-versa.

And the below job does not shows the expected behaviour.

```
public void textChange() 
{ 
       int i, j; 
       int L = 12; 
       int h = 4; 
       int t = 54; 
       str tmpStr; 
   ;  

  i =  strLen(strKeep(seField.text(), '\n')); 
  info(seField.text() + ' Lines: ' + int2str(i)); 
  super(); 
  if (i >= H) 
 { 
  error(strFmt("max lines = %1", h));  
 } 
} 

   Actually i am trying to implement something like-
```

in a textChange method of stringEdit when i enter "A"(or any value) it should display "A line 0"(in info log) then i enter B it should display "AB line 0" (in info). Once i press enter and the enter "Q" display shoud be something like "AB Line 0"(1st line) "Q Line 1"(2nd line) and so on. I face problem with "\n"(Enter) So I need to achieve this through ASCII value. Thanks.

Comment: Are you interested in specific keystrokes, you have a specific task?

Comment: No, no specific keystrokes. Actually i am trying to implement something like- in a textChange method of stringEdit when i enter "A"(or any value) it should display "A line 0"(in info log) then i enter B it should display "AB line 0" (in info). Once i press enter and the enter "Q" display shoud be something like "AB Line 0"(1st line) "Q Line 1"(2nd line) and so on. I face problem with "\n"(Enter) So I need to achieve this through ASCII value(and also could you tell me how to store/display keystrokes). Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how `task()` is going to help you.

It seems that when the `StringEdit` control contains carriage returns, `StringEdit.text()` is always giving a wrong result when you're checking it in the `textChange()` method. Probably an AX bug. You can use the `modified()` method to get the correct result at least afterwards.

```
Exportfile for AOT version 1.0 or later
Formatversion: 1

***Element: FRM

; Microsoft Dynamics AX Forms unloaded
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FRMVERSION 5

FORM #TestForm1
  PROPERTIES
    Name                #TestForm1
  ENDPROPERTIES

  METHODS
    Version: 3
    SOURCE #updateOutput
      #void updateOutput()
      #{
      #    container c = str2con(Input.text(), '\n');
      #    int i;
      #    str s;
      #    ;
      #
      #    for (i = 1; i <= conlen(c); i++)
      #        s += strfmt("Line %1: %2\n", i, conpeek(c, i));
      #
      #    Output.text(s);
      #}
    ENDSOURCE
    SOURCE #classDeclaration
      #public class FormRun extends ObjectRun
      #{
      #
      #}
    ENDSOURCE
  ENDMETHODS
  OBJECTBANK
    PROPERTIES
    ENDPROPERTIES

  ENDOBJECTBANK

  JOINS
  ENDJOINS

  DESIGN
    PROPERTIES
    ENDPROPERTIES

    CONTAINER
      CONTROL STRINGEDIT
        PROPERTIES
          Name                #Input
          AutoDeclaration     #Yes
          Width               #Column width
          Height              #Column height
          MultiLine           #Yes
        ENDPROPERTIES

        METHODS
          Version: 3
          SOURCE #modified
            #public boolean modified()
            #{
            #    boolean ret = super();
            #    ;
            #
            #    element.updateOutput();
            #
            #    return ret;
            #}
          ENDSOURCE
          SOURCE #textChange
            #public void textChange()
            #{
            #    super();
            #
            #    element.updateOutput();
            #}
          ENDSOURCE
        ENDMETHODS
      ENDCONTROL

      CONTROL STRINGEDIT
        PROPERTIES
          Name                #Output
          AutoDeclaration     #Yes
          AllowEdit           #No
          Width               #Column width
          MultiLine           #Yes
        ENDPROPERTIES

      ENDCONTROL

    ENDCONTAINER

  ENDDESIGN

ENDFORM

***Element: END
```

**Update.** You can probably trigger the `modified()` method from `textChange()` - that would be a hack, I didn't try it.

Comment: Thanks alot for the .xpo I tried it but still there is an issue. After pressing enter it shows unexpected behaviour in line 3, line 4 ...Okay I am trying to do that.

Comment: the task() method would help me with storing the keystrokes http://www.axaptapedia.com/Task_macro (i needed the info for my knowledge :D)

Comment: See the update in my answer above: remove the `modified()` method from the form and update the `textChanged()` method as follows: `public void textChange() { super(); this.modified(); element.updateOutput(); }` - the result will be correct, hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to store keystrokes in an AX form is use the `task()` method on the form.

But do not do it for the purpose you commented on!

Rather use a enum value or a combobox feeded with the relevant values to get the wanted behavior.

**UPDATE:**
You may find some useful information on this subject here: http://www.axaptapedia.com/FormComboBoxControl
and here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/palle_agermark/archive/2005/06/30/434146.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jan for the response. Through task() can i store ASCII values? could you site an example? Okay I will try combobox to achieve it the way you suggested. I put the code in the thread kindly have a look. Thanks once again.

Comment: Why ASCII, AX use Unicode? Search for method name "task" in forms.

Comment: okay thanks again for the info..yeah i found the method, was looking for an example on how to use it.

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi Jan, I was looking for an example for method task() which i found in http://www.axaptapedia.com/Task_macro and also, using combobox like you said i have to feed the whole values in advance for desired behaiour. Cant i gain the expected behaviour using the code above(in my thread) which is in textChange() of StringEdit. If you run my code you will get a clear idea of what I am tying to do.  I think i have to make use of macro- task, keypressed etc. Well I am trying. Thanks once again!

Comment: I am not going to test your code! What is the number of expected values in the combobox? It may be the easiest way out.

Comment: nevermind :) the thread is resolved. Thanks 4 your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `SearchMode` attribute of string control. To be useful the string value has to be mapped to an indexed table field.