# Prevent adding white space in VATNum

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

In TaxVatNumTable form, i need to eliminate white spaces in the field VATNum when a new record is inserted. Now, what i already did is to override the modifiedField method on the TaxVatNumTable:

```
public void modifiedField(FieldId _fieldId)
{
   super(_fieldId);

   switch (_fieldId)
   {
        case fieldNum(TaxVATNumTable, VATNum):
        this.VATNum = strRem(this.VATNum," ");
        break;
    }
}
```

Works pretty well but is there another way to accomplish this? I am thinking at something like OnPreviewKeyDown event in WPF, check the pressed key and if space, do nothing. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you take a look at `textChange()` method? See [Store Keystrokes in X++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401570/store-keystrokes-in-x) and [Creating custom instant search filters in Ax 2009 and 2012](https://jkmsdax2012.wordpress.com/tag/google-filter/)

Comment: @FH-Inway i've just tried to add  this.text(strrem(this.text()," ")) in the textChange but some exception occurs and i am not able to catch it or i don't know how..

Comment: @FH-Inway, i think i have to extend TaxVATNumValidate and override validateVATNum method. I will take this approach, it seems the right way.

Comment: Please do not use data validation methods to change data.

Comment: @FH-Inway thanks for your last comment, i was not sure about this. I won't. In fact, i am using that validation approach just to make some checks and pop up some warnings and of course return false from validateVATnum method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have done it is the best way to do it.
The `TextChange` method implies test for each keystroke, never do that in AX.

Comment: That's a good thing, i learned about avoiding TextChange for each key pressed and not to change the data when validating.